# Is there a way to abort an executing asynchronous function from outside the function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous function that takes some time to complete execution. Before it is able to do so, it can be called again with new data, in which case the previous call isn't necessary anymore, so I want to abort it. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to add something like `if (abort_function) return;` after each instruction in the function.

I have tried to understand how the [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) interface works to see if it was able to do just that, but I couldn't get it to abort the function and I'm unsure if it's able to or if it's for something similar but different (to abort an asynchronous server `fetch` and a single `Promise` being awaited, I think).

Here's a minimal example of the problem:

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');
const div = document.createElement('div');
const sleep = milliseconds => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
const on_input = async () => {
  const value = input.value;
  console.log(`Asynchronous function started. Value: ${value}.`);
  for (let index = 1; index <= 10; index++) {
    await sleep(500);
    console.log(`${index * 10}% completed. Value: ${value}.`);
  }
  div.textContent = value;
};
input.addEventListener('input', on_input);
document.body.append(input, div);
```

Comment: _"I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to add something like if (abort_function) return; after each instruction in the function."_ I'm afraid it's likely that you're going to have to do something lke this. With a bit of thought though I'm sure you could limit the number of checks required.

Comment: @phuzi That's unfortunate if that's the case. I was hoping that there might exist some better way to do it.

Comment: Things like `AbortController` and `fetch` are not implemented in JavaScript and there may be better ways to implement the abort functionality. Whenever I've needed to do something similar in C# with `CancellationTokens` I've ended up checking in a loop or had to pepper the checks throughout the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to interrupt a running function at an arbitrary point. Part of the issue here is that unless you're spawning another process (workers), non-IO work is happening in a single thread.

To leverage AbortController, or any other abort pattern, you do need to check if the signal has been aborted at various "checkpoints" in your abortable function.

An example of AbortController:

```js
function f(signal) {
    console.log('Some work.')
    signal.throwIfAborted()
    console.log('More work.')
    signal.throwIfAborted()
    console.log('Even more work.')
}

const abortController = new AbortController()
setTimeout(() => f(abortController.signal), 500)

abortController.abort()
```

Comment: That example seems basically the same as checking a variable and returning if the condition is true, so I'm not sure what the `AbortController` adds of usefulness in this situation at least. I did tried making a function that returns a Promise which listens for the [abort event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/abort_event), then calls the `Promise`'s resolution or rejection function and has a `.then()` / `.catch()` but the `Promise`'s code would continue being executed until the end.

Comment: The AbortController provides a standard interface and also can be passed to some IO operations like `fetch` to cancel those requests as well.